# Access service running on host machine from app in Windows Subsystem for Android

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-android

I'm trying to connect to a service running in a docker container on my host machine, e.g. https://local-account.dev.com

We have several microservices running in kubernetes in Azure but in order to test/debug code we can run 1 or more of those services locally in docker containers. During the debug process the `hosts` file gets updated to direct traffic to that service to the local machine. e.g.

```
127.0.0.1 local-account.dev.com
```

I'm trying to hit a url from that service from my app running in WSA.

When there is no entry in the `hosts` file the cloud hosted service is hit as expected, when the entry is present in the `hosts` file the connection times out but I don't see any activity on my service.

I have tried using my assigned IP address as well as 127.0.0.1 and have tried this with "Advanced networking" enabled and disabled.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to hit the service at 127.0.0.1 from Azure intending to hit the service running on a separate machine running WSA?

Comment: @Ramhound Nope, App running in WSA accessing service on the host machine. I'll try and clear up the question.